# Is IFileDialog compatible with C?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Question speaks for itself. I have a program that used SHBrowseforfolder, but now they want me to upgrade it to IFileDialog which I made but is in C++, so is it even possible to get it to work with C since it's OOP?

Comment: Yes, since it's a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) interface.

Comment: @cremno: The answer section is down there bud ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: It may be worthwhile to write a small C++ wrapper, declared `extern "C"`.

Comment: *Object-oriented programming* is not a feature of a programming language, but rather a way of structuring code. The Windows API is undoubtedly implemented in an object-oriented fashion, yet exposes all it's services through a C interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IFileDialog is part of Microsoft's Component Object Model (COM). COM programming can be done in C. Quite tedious though.

Here's a tutorial (can't vouch for it's quality)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the client side is considerably less omfgwtf-hideous than actually implementing COM objects in C (to which, I completely concur with you, having done it many moons ago).

Comment: The thing is though, I've read that and I still have no idea where to even start on converting all that.

Comment: It's not so bad if you are merely the client side. `p->function(args)` becomes `p->lpVtbl->function(p, args)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is C code to print the name of a selected folder using `IFileDialog`:

```c
#include <shobjidl_core.h> //somewhere in your program
//...
IFileDialog *pfd;
IShellItem *psiResult;
PWSTR pszFilePath = NULL;
if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IFileOpenDialog, &pfd))){
  pfd->lpVtbl->SetOptions(pfd, FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
  pfd->lpVtbl->Show(pfd, hwnd);
  if (SUCCEEDED(pfd->lpVtbl->GetResult(pfd, &psiResult))){
    if (SUCCEEDED(psiResult->lpVtbl->GetDisplayName(psiResult, SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath))){
      WCHAR *p = pszFilePath;
      while (*p){
        printf("%c",*p);//I don't like unicode
        p++;
      }
      CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
    }
    psiResult->lpVtbl->Release(psiResult);
  }
  pfd->lpVtbl->Release(pfd);
}
```